# How can I permanently change an app's location to the SD card

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g2

I have some applications on my Moto G2 that I want to store in the SD card.

But each time I update an app that is on the card, it migrates to the phone memory - every single time.

Is there a fix for this?